# React Image Rendering using require()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image

I'm trying to render images in react using require().
Below is a snapshot of the code that is working.

```
const ProjectBlock: React.FC<{ data: PROJECTBLOCK }> = (props) => {
  const baseUrl = "../../../assets/images/forkify.png";
  return (
    <div className="projectblock">
      <div className="projectblock__heading">
        <h3 className="subheading-default margin-bottom">{props.data.heading}</h3>
        <p className="para">{props.data.content}</p>
        <h4 className="smallheadin">{props.data.technologies.join(" · ")}</h4>
      </div>
      <img
        src={require("../../../assets/images/forkify.png")}
        alt=""
        className="projectblock__image"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the above case, I'm passing a string to the require() function. However when I try and store the string in the baseUrl variable and pass it to the require() function, it does not work and gives the following error in the console.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../../assets/images/forkify.png'
```

Here is how I am trying to use the variable with require()

```
const ProjectBlock: React.FC<{ data: PROJECTBLOCK }> = (props) => {
  const baseUrl = "../../../assets/images/forkify.png";
  return (
    <div className="projectblock">
      <div className="projectblock__heading">
        <h3 className="subheading-default margin-bottom">{props.data.heading}</h3>
        <p className="para">{props.data.content}</p>
        <h4 className="smallheadin">{props.data.technologies.join(" · ")}</h4>
      </div>
      <img src={require(baseUrl)} alt="" className="projectblock__image" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Have even tried with template literals.
Please help!

Comment: Are you using some online editor like codesandbox or locally on VS Code? Also why is `require` necessary? You can simply do `import forkify from "../../../assets/images/forkify.png"'` & `<img src={forkify} .. />`

Comment: That works after editing the ts.config file however I want to set a baseURL and append paths based on data I get from props. That does not work for some reason even though the concatenated path is the same.